# How to fill out multiple sheets everytime a Google Form is submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have created a very simple Apps Script that based on the answers provided through a Google Form, makes a copy of a template (a sheet in the form answers spreadsheet) and fills it out with the entered info. This is part of the code:

```
function fichas() {
var formato = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ficha = formato.duplicateActiveSheet();
var respuestas = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID').getSheetByName('Form Responses');

var name = respuestas.getRange(**2**, 5);
var apellido = ficha.getRange(4, 2);
name.copyTo(apellido);

var name2 = respuestas.getRange(**2**, 6);
var apellido2 = ficha.getRange(4, 3);
name2.copyTo(apellido2);
```

The bold number represents the first user's information. I have set up a trigger that runs the script when the form is submitted. Now, what I don't know how to do is how to move to the next row to use the next user's info (in other words I want to automatically increase that bold number by one everytime the script runs). Is it possible? I am new to this and I am trying to learn but sometimes it is too hard!

I really appreciate your help!

Jorge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a variable that is common to all users and that you increment on each form submission. There are a few possible ways to achieve that, why not try [script Properties ?](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/script-properties#setProperty%28String,String%29) it is fairly simple to implement :

First initialize it with a statement like this :

```
ScriptProperties.setProperty('rowValue', 1);// this must happen only once, you could insert it in a small function to "initialize"
```

and then in your code you can retrieve it using

```
var rowValue = Number(ScriptProperties.getProperty('rowValue'));
```

increment it using `rowValue++` and write it back to the storage ... remember that you can always edit this value directly in the script properties (script editor>file>project properties> project properties)

```
ScriptProperties.setProperty('rowValue', rowValue);
```

This would be perfect if you never get more than one user sending a form simultaneously.
In this case there is a risk that the script mixes values...

There is another service designed to handle this situation : [the lock service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/?hl=en)

the doc gives an explicit example on how to implement it : it goes simply like this :

```
 var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
 try {
   lock.waitLock(10000);
 } catch (e) {
   Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 10 seconds.');
 }
```

do what you have to do, increment the counter... and when your done use

```
lock.releaseLock();
```

it might seem complicated but it's not ;-) and it will work flawlessly in every possible situation... just give it a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! As I mentioned before I am learning to do this and I have no experience in programming at all... Honestly speaking I tried to do what you suggested but it is not really clear to me how to do it, so obviously I could not make it work. Could you please help me? I really appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: What do you mean by 'write it back to storage'? I can make the script fill out my template but I can't increase the rowValue for the subsequent templates.